# Centering Text In CSS

Tags: html, css, center

I'm sorry I know this is SUPER simple but I cannot figure this out.

Here is my current Css style

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent+Pro:100);
html { 
}
#overlay {
font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 7em;
margin: .2em .5em;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
position: fixed;
right: 0;
}
video#bgvid { 
position: fixed; 
right: 0; 
top: 0;
width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
}
```

**How can I center #overlay?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-align:center`. You may need to give it a width too like 100% if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Wow that simple, also found out it was the positioning of where I was placing it in the Css works now thanks!